# Aurelia two-way binding in custom element not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker, aurelia

Trying to learn Aurelia 1.0 and I can't seem to get two-way binding on a custom element to work.

Using bootstrap-datepicker I made a date-range-picker custom element:

date-range-picker.js

```
import {bindable, bindingMode, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'jquery';
import datepicker from 'bootstrap-datepicker';

@inject(Element)
export class DateRangePicker {
  @bindable startName = 'start';
  @bindable endName = 'end';
  @bindable startValue = null;
  @bindable endValue = null;

  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached() {
    $(this.element).find('.input-daterange').datepicker();
  }
}
```

date-range-picker.html

```
<template>
  <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" 
      name="${startName}" id="${startName}" 
      value.two-way="startValue" 
      placeholder="Start Date (mm/dd/yyy)" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
    <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" 
      name="${endName}" id="${endName}" 
      value.two-way="endValue" 
      placeholder="End Date (mm/dd/yyy)"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

the custom element is used in leads.html:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <form role="form" class="form-inline" submit.delegate="search()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <date-range-picker 
        start-name="createdAtStartDate" start-value.two-way="startDate" 
        end-name="createdAtEndDate" end-value.two-way="endDate">  
      </date-range-picker>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

leads.js

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {LeadsService} from './leads-service';
import moment from 'moment';

@inject(LeadsService)
export class Leads {
  startDate = moment().format('M/D/YYYY');
  endDate = moment().format('M/D/YYYY');
  leads = [];

  constructor(dataService) {
    this.dataService = dataService;
  }

  search() {
    this.dataService.getLeads({
      startDate: this.startDate,
      endDate: this.endDate
    })
   .then(leads => this.leads = leads);
  }
}
```

date-range-picker works as expected and whatever value is set at startDate and endDate in the leads.js is properly bound to the input boxes in the custom element but when I submit the form startDate and endDate doesn't change even if I change the values of the input boxes.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are being updated by javascript, so you have to dispatch the input's change event, like this:

```
 attached() {
    $(this.element).find('.input-daterange').datepicker()
      .on('changeDate', e => {
        e.target.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      });
  }
```

Here's a running example https://gist.run/?id=5d047c561cf5973cf98e88bae12f4b4e

Comment: I actually tried that first but I still get the same result. I changed both startValue and endValue to specify the defaultBindingMode as you stated but still doesn't work. I tried not using a custom element and just using input text boxes and the two-way binding works. It seems that it doesn't work with custom elements.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make any difference but try removing the "= null" from bindable declaration. `@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) startValue; // no = null here`

Comment: Unfortunately even after removing the "= null" the two-way binding still does not work. 
`@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) startValue;`

Comment: Ohh I know why, the value is being updated by javascript. You have to listen to some "change" method, and then call this.element.dispatchEvent. I'll write an example when I have time

Comment: It works Fabio! Thanks! Ok so just to understand what's going on, the bootstrap-picker javascript is the one updating the input boxes which are bound to startValue from the leads view model. But since it's the javascript code, there's no change event that triggers the two way binding?

Comment: yes. As a solution, we are "forcing" the change event

Comment: Moving forward, should I always dispatch a 'change' event for components that have two-way binding?

Comment: No. You should only dispatch a 'change event' if the 'change event' is not being triggered normal, which usually happens when the property is updated via javascript

Comment: This just made my day. Only example out there, that i could find, that works. Thanks